# How to implement a trait for another trait in rust?

Tags: function, rust, struct, format, traits

I have a trait called DataValue in my rust project, and all of my "DataValue" structs inherit from it and the trait itself is used to define shared functionality so that I can store "any" DataValue within a Box.

```rust
pub trait DataValue: Debug {
    fn serialize(
        &self,
    ) -> (
        PropertyType, /* serialized type */
        String,       /* serialized value */
    );

    fn ind_clone(&self) -> Box<dyn DataValue>;

    fn deserialize(
        serialized_type: &PropertyType,
        serialized_value: &str,
    ) -> Option<Box<dyn DataValue>>
    where
        Self: Sized;

    fn get_type(&self) -> PropertyType {
        self.serialize().0
    }

    fn get_value(&self) -> Box<dyn std::any::Any>;
}
```

I want any DataValue inheriting struct to implement fmt::Display, and implementing fmt::Display for my use case is as simple as concatenating the two values returned by the serialize function. How can I implement the fmt::Display trait for the DataValue struct, and then define the fmt function that as stated before takes in the values returned by the serialize function.

Pseudo code:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for DataValue {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}: {}", self.serialize().0, self.serialize().1)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible the way you describe it. Since `DataValue` can be implemented for any type, including types that already have a `Display` implementation, this type of blanket implementation is prohibited by Rust's coherence rules. Rust has an imcomplete und unstable specialization features that will enable blanket implementations like this one.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I don't think `specialization` will enable [external blanket implementations](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3cf9e6c7cbb3a7eb690695a7cb8c0a43)

Comment: @cafce25 You are right, this will only work for traits defined in the same crate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called a blanket implementation and would be written like this:

```rust
impl<T: DataValue> fmt::Display for T {

    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}: {}", self.serialize().0, self.serialize().1)
    }
}
```

The problem with that is that you can't create blanket implementations for foreign traits, and `fmt::Display` obviously is one.
So the answer is it can't be done.

Instead you could include a method `display` for your trait and return a wrapper that implements `Display`:

```rust
trait DataValue: Debug {
    // …
    fn display(&self) -> DisplayDataValue<&Self>
    {
        DisplayDataValue(self)
    }
}
pub struct DisplayDataValue<T>(T);

impl<T: DataValue> fmt::Display for DisplayDataValue<&'_ T> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let ser = self.0.serialize();
        write!(f, "{}: {}", ser.0, ser.1)
    }
}
```

With `#![feature(return_position_impl_trait_in_trait)]` we could hide that implementation and just return something implementing `Display` and wouldn't need to export `DisplayDataValue`:

```rust
    fn display(&self) -> impl fmt::Display + '_
```